# How can I have the ground sampling distance from the images?

Tags: remote-sensing, aerial-photography, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, orthophoto, photogrammetry

I have some aerial images and I need to know how if I can have the ground sampling distance value from the image without calculate it from the plane fly's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In (my) question and answer [Georeference single drone image from EXIF data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384756/georeference-single-drone-image-from-exif-data), there is a calculation for the horizontal field of view (in metres) of a UAV image with given lens characteristics, pitch, and altitude.

For pitch -90 degrees, i.e. pointing straight down, this reduces to

```
ground_fov_horiz = altitude * sensor_width / focal_length
```

If you divide this by the number of pixels in the image horizontally, you should get the GSD.

Example for a Mavic mini at altitude 100m:

```
ground_fov_horiz = 100m * 6.17mm / 4.36mm = 142m
GSD = 142m / 4000 pixels = 3.5 cm/pixel
```

Alternatively, a lot of software for UAV route planning does it for you, for instance the mapping component of dronelink.com.

You have to be a bit careful since the camera focal length is usually specified prior to any sensor lens corrections. So you may be a few percent off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand "ground sampling distance" for an area, but assume you mean the pixel resolution of the image.If the images are geo-rectified, then you can just zoom in until you can see the pixels, then use a measuring tool to get the pixel width in whatever software you have. Otherwise, I think you could  estimate the distance across the image and divide by the number of pixels across the image.