Using trigonometry to compute the position of an object inside of a drone picture
Assume I have a certain picture taken aerially by a drone. The yaw, pitch, and roll of the drone gimbal are known, and so are the horizontal and vertical FoV of the camera. We also know the x, y, and z coordinates the drone had while taking the picture.
In order to determine whether a point, given its x, y, z coordinates (for example in UTM), is inside of the field of view of the image, I have been using the following algorithm:

Compute rotation matrices for yaw, pitch, and roll:



Construct the combined rotation matrix (R) as the product of these three matrices: R = R_yaw • R_pitch • R_roll

Compute the view vector as:




Multiply R^T by the view vector: R^T • view_vector

Calculate the vertical and horizontal angle of the object with respect to the drone point of view:


Let t_1, t_2, t_3 be the first, second, and third element of R • view_vector.


The point is in the image if:

. If so, we compute the relative pixels at which the object is located as:


We multiply x_rel, y_rel times the image's width and height respectively to finally get the x, y position of the point(s) in the image.
After trying out this procedure with some real images and point coordinates, I find that it often gives quite inaccurate results.
For example, in the picture below points 1, 2, 3, and 5 are pretty close to their detected positions (red marker), and there's a false positive for point 4. However, it doesn't look like I would be able to get points 1, 2, 3, and 5 to get to their correct position by simply rotating the picture (i.e. changing the yaw): there does seem to be some distortion going on.

I shared a Python implementation of the algorithm outlined here, with a test image + GCP coordinates to try it. This could help better visualize the calculations being done. Feel free to try it with different data.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RyRqqgmpOCH7elqE4_spCjAD2h61NRmY?usp=sharing
Am I making any mistakes in the various steps? Is there a better way to accomplish this task altogether?

I think the problem is the quality of the IMU, the quality of the GNSS sensors, CMOS cropping, and post processing affecting the focal length of the images.  Look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384756/georeference-single-drone-image-from-exif-data and here https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-fn_j?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop
